# Python replacing "\" character twice replace funtion

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, escaping

I have text for fuzzy searching where user gives text, and I replace with characters used for regex parsing later.

Here is the text saved in configuration_blocks variable:

```
neighbor 10.1.(()).(())
```

Here is the code:

```py
configuration_blocks = [sub.replace("$", ".*").replace("(())", "\S+") for sub in configuration_blocks]
```

However, the result is `neighbor 10.1.\ \S` with two backslashes.

How can I do this to get one backslash only?

Comment: Where do you see the result?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use a single backslash in your string you need to escape it will another backslash like \. So in your code you do this:

configuration_blocks = [sub.replace("$", ".*").replace("(())", "\S+") for sub in configuration_blocks]

you might still get double backslash in the console but in the regex context, it will behave as the single backslash.

if you want to see the string as a single backslash in the console use raw text like this (`r""`)

Comment: did you mean to add a double slash in the code above

Comment: oh sorry for the typo, please check the answer again

Comment: It worked. You were correct, the double slashS was read as \S when parsing the regex.

Comment: Glad to know, please upvote and tick the answer as correct if it worked for you.